# using firebase geofire in IOS App

Tags: objective-c, firebase, geofire

I am to looking for a quick way to implement a dynamic location based filtering of points of interest feature in an iOS App - where a user's location continuously changes and as a result the points of interest will continuously change.

I see that firebase geofire has a similar feature but written in .js. Can you advise if this can be leveraged in an iOS App with no webviews?

Comment: I quickly scanned the Geofire code (https://github.com/firebase/geoFire/blob/gh-pages/geoFire.js) and it seems quite readable and unusually self-contained. How about having a go at it yourself? If you're asking if someone already converted that Geofire's JavaScript to Objective-C then your question is off-topic.

Comment: You are right..I am unfamiliar with .js and want to know if it can be converted to Objective C and ideally if somebody has done the conversion.

Comment: Nobody has done this. It can certainly be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoFire now has an [Objective-C library](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc)!